# Sending money to customers through paypal

Tags: node.js, paypal

For our application we are accepting payments to our account through Braintree. However, after a particular action has occurred we need to send money from the brain tree account to the desired customers account. I have been looking at the payouts API (node js) but this only allows me to send payments to customers who have an associated PayPal account. I would also like to send payments to customers who do not own a PayPal account. Does PayPal support anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Payouts is the solution to your answer. This is how it will work:

1. If the recipient has a PayPal account it will be credited to the PayPal Account.
2. If the recipient does not have a PayPal account then they can sign up to receive the amount and then move it to their bank account.